# Replace @PathVariable object with ID only for Springdoc

Tags: java, spring, openapi, springfox, springdoc

I am currently trying to migrate from Springfox to Springdoc.

Most of my endpoints contain a `@PathVariable Instance`. Obviously I am only passing in the ID of the instance and Spring would automatically resolve the object for me.

Here is an example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/{instance}/role")
public class RoleController {

  @GetMapping()
  public ResponseEntity<?> getRoles(@PathVariable Instance instance) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
  
}
```

Called as `/api/myInstance/role`.

Springfox would handle this correctly for me, only generating `{instance}` as a `String` mapping to the ID of `Instance`. However, Springdoc expects the entire object to be passed as a path param.

I did try this so far, however it didn't seem to have any effect:

```
static {
  SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceParameterObjectWithClass(Instance.class, String.class);
}
```

If possible, I'd like to avoid annotating hundreds of endpoints with the same annotation and solve this on a global level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own `ParameterCustomizer`:

```
@Component
public class InstanceParameterCustomizer implements org.springdoc.core.customizers.ParameterCustomizer {
    @Override
    public Parameter customize(Parameter parameterModel, MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        if (Instance.class.equals(methodParameter.getParameterType()) && methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(PathVariable.class) != null) {
            parameterModel.setName("id"); // if you need to change the name  ...
            parameterModel.setSchema(new StringSchema());
        }
        return parameterModel;
    }
}
```